# What is the update frequency of the zipcode and addresses of Here in respect to the Netherlands (BAG / Kadaster)?

Tags: here-api, bag

The dutch zip-codes and addresses are administered by a government agency called "kadaster". 
They make this data available in something called the "BAG".

I would like to know how and how-quickly new zip-codes are available in the Here Location Service.
Is there a resource with more details on this?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on the use case relevant to the zip code usage. In case you want to provide any feedback, please refer https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-feedback/dev_guide/topics/example-address-feedback.html

Comment: The context is that we have a website. On this website a user can enter address information. We want the user to fill in their zip-code and housenumber. We want the site to auto-fll the streetname and city. This to improve data quality.

In the Netherlands we are building new streets very often. We would like to know how quickly these changes are know in Here.

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete API enables searching using free text address and provide zip-code and street details can come, when the address matches. Please refer example adds geocoding autocompletion to an HTML text box. Start typing in the text-box below to see the responses returned. Markers are also added to a map to show the suggested locations. Clicking on a map marker will move the map and display more information about the selected location.